# Haskell and typeclasses with multiple parameters

Tags: haskell

I'm having a simple problem when it comes to writing up typeclasses that inherit from one another. I'm trying to create a hierarchy of typeclasses to achieve some level of representational abstraction. Let's say I want a collections typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Collection c a where
  isMember :: a -> c -> Bool
```

And I've defined a tree type:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I'd like to make my tree a collection, so:

```
inOrder :: Tree a -> [a]
inOrder Empty = []
inOrder (Node a l r) = (inOrder l) ++ [a] ++ (inOrder r)

instance (Eq a) => Collection (Tree a) a where
  isMember a c = a `elem` (inOrder c)
```

This doesn't quite work right:

```
*Main> (isMember '2' Empty)
<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (Collection (Tree a) Char)
      arising from a use of `isMember' at <interactive>:1:1-18
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Collection (Tree a) Char)
    In the expression: (isMember '2' Empty)
    In the definition of `it': it = (isMember '2' Empty)
```

Presumably the value of the typeclass would be lost if I had to create an implementation for each concrete type. So I'm not writing the instance declaration correctly. But I can't quite figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that, by default, each type class parameter is independent of the others. Simply applying `isMember` to a `Char` and a tree of unknown element type isn't enough to let it deduce that it should use the (seemingly obvious) instance.

This is clearly not how you want it to work, and a bit silly to boot, but that's how it works. To deal with the problem, you need to give it some way of making the connection, for which there are other extensions: `FunctionalDependencies` is the more common, while `TypeFamilies` is newer and much nicer to use, but still has some rough edges.

With functional dependencies, you would specify that some subset of the type class parameters *fully determine* others, e.g. `Collection c a | c -> a`. This has its own pitfalls, but works well enough in many cases.

With type families, you would probably reduce this to a single-parameter type class, with the element type associated, e.g.:

```
class Collection c where
    type Elem c
    isMember :: Elem c -> c -> Bool
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a functional dependency to indicate that the container type determines the element type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Collection c a | c -> a where
    ...
```

There are also other ways of doing this, like using type families, but I think this is the simplest fix in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Empty`'s type is `Tree a` and ghc doesn't have enough information to know that you want the `a` to be `Char` in this case. If you manually specify the type, it works:

```
isMember '2' (Empty::Tree Char)
```

The reason ghc can't just infer that `a` needs to be `Char` is that theoretically you could have one instance `Collection (Tree Char) Char` and another `Collection (Tree Int) Char`. In that case there would be no way to infer which one should be used, unless you specify so explicitly.